# Client socket not connecting to server socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I'm trying to transfer a message between two android phones over the local network. I read sockets where a good way to do this. 
(I cant use bluetooth)
(I cant use NFC either)

I have built a server and client application.

One app has a server that listens for a connection. 
The other app has a client that tries to connect when a button is pressed.

Both the manifest files contain the correct permissions. (with the html tags) 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /
             
uses-permission >android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/

I put the server online first:

```
      ServerSocket myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(27024);
      System.out.println("Server is waiting for incoming connection on host=" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + ", port=" + myServerSocket.getLocalPort());
      Socket socket = myServerSocket.accept();
```

Then try and connect with the client.

```
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 27024;

            try{
                System.out.println("Client attempting to connect to server at host: " + host + ", port: " + port);
                Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

                //This below line never gets called :(
                System.out.println("Client socked created! Now trying to send data to server");

               }
```

In my console: 
Client attempting to connect to server at host: localhost, port: 27024

The "Client socked created!" line never gets output.

Both hosts are set to "localhost" and the port number is the same. 
I've tried various ports, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
String host = "localhost";
int port = 27024;
```

You realize that your client needs to be given the IP address of the server, right?

*Note* you will most likely not be able to, or ever should, bind an app on a non WiFi interface.

Comment: but both client and server are on the local network, the localhost?

Comment: `localhost` refers to the device the application is running, and the address will always be `127.0.0.1`, a local loop back. Using this address, packets never leave the device. You need to use each devices IP on the other.

Comment: oh god that makes me feel stupid, i now understand why the guys example worked i was watching on youtube - because he was running the client and server from one machine.

Comment: Ok, I have an emulated phone running, and a real phone - trying to connect them both. I've entered the emulated phone (server) as the host of the client application (host ip is 10.0.2.15). But am having no luck connecting

Comment: Emulated phone? What do you mean? An Emulator? Tell where your server is running on. And tell exactly where your client is running on. You cannot use an emulator and a phone. But you had two phones wasnt it? Tell us the ip of the server phone. Tell us the ip of the client phone. (the ip of the client phone further is irrelevant).

Comment: Hello I was running an emulated phone from android studio. I also had my real HTC phone plugged in. I was trying to connect them both. Anyway it looks like i've found a tutorial to do so, but thank you both for helping.

Comment: this is a link i found, should be the solution, but havent tried it yet - https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/